# What is the proper way to do multiple UPDATE statements?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a server which sends up to 20  `UPDATE` statements to a separate MySQL server every 3-5 seconds for a game. My question is, is it faster to concat them together(`UPDATE;UPDATE;UPDATE`). Is it faster to do them in a transaction then commit the transaction? Is it faster to just do each `UPDATE` individually?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I edited out the _non-query_ terminology you were using, as it would imply statements like option or variable setting to a lot of readers.  I just called them `UPDATE` statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on how the server connects. If the connection between the servers is persistent, you probably won't see a great deal of difference between concatenated statements or multiple separate statements.

However, if the execution involves establishing the connection, executing the SQL statement, then tearing down the connection, you will save a lot of resources on the database server by executing multiple statements at a time.  The process of establishing the connection tends to be an expensive and time-consuming one, and has the added overhead of DNS resolution since the machines are separate.

It makes the most logical sense to me to establish the connection, begin a transaction, execute the statements individually, commit the transaction and disconnect from the database server.  Whether you send all the `UPDATE` statements as a single concatenation or multiple individual statements is probably not going to make a big difference in this scenario, especially if this just involves regular communication between these two servers and you need not expect it to scale up with user load, for example.

The use of the transaction assumes that your 3-5 second periodic bursts of `UPDATE` statements are logically related somehow. If they are not interdependent, then you could skip the transaction saving some resources.

As with any question regarding performance, the best answer is *if your current system is meeting your performance and scaling needs, you ought not pay too much attention to micro-optimizing it just yet.*

Comment: "It makes the most logical sense to me to establish the connection, begin a transaction, execute the statements individually, commit the transaction and disconnect from the database server." -- curious, why to begin a transaction? It adds some overhead, but if queries are independent it doesn't worth it, does it?

Comment: @zerkms Are they independent? My reading of the OP is that they are logically grouped, which implies transaction to me. I'll add a note above.

Comment: "Is it faster to just do each UPDATE individually?" --- if OP accepts doing them "individually" - then they are independent

Comment: we are seeing some over usage of cpu resources on our RDS instance for this. Amazon RDS Micro instance. So we are trying to find places to optimize to stay within a micro instance for longer. We will eventually need to move out of a micro but trying to stay in it as long as possible for cost

Comment: They are individual updates to multiple peoples players. I don't know that a transaction makes sense in this case

Comment: @user1725959 If you are setting up and tearing down a connection for each statement at this point (which isn't clear), you should see a significant savings by grouping them under a single connection.

Comment: I utilize the MySqlHelper class in connector/net which may or may not decide to keep the connection open for reuse. It is logically ontrolled within the connector. I'm fairly certain that it will open them and close then when they are no longer needed but will keep them open as needed. Though the more calls coming in the more connections it will create.

Answer (score 1):

It is always faster to wrap these UPDATEs into single transaction block.
Price for this is that if anything fails inside that block it would be that nothing happened at all - you will have to repeat your work again.

Aslo, keep in mind that transactions in MySQL only work when using InnoDB engine.